# Переменные окружения Linux, передать в Python скрипт

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

Хочу написать скрипт на python для проведения инвентаризации машин на linux. Подскажите пожалуйста как передать переменные окружения linux в скрипт на python.
Как то так?

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(os.environ['HOME'])
```

Comment: А что Вас смущает в Вашем варианте? Какого поведения ожидаете от представленного Вами кода и что в этом поведении не соответствует ожиданиям? Единственный нюанс, вместо `os.environ['HOME']` лучше использовать `os.environ.get('HOME')` так Вы избежите исключений в случае отсутствия запрашиваемой переменной

Comment: просто хотел узнать как лучше  это сделать. Не совсем понятно для чего "if __name__ == '__main__':"

Comment: В Python каждый модуль может быть импортирован другим модулем, то есть быть *библиотекой*. Данная *идиома* служит для того, чтобы в таком случае модуль **не** исполнялся как основной. *Библиотека*: `import foo`. Исполнение: `python foo.py`. Возьмите `ipython` (`i` - это не опечатка), и проверьте сами разницу.

Answer (score 0):

Просто запускайте как-то так:

```
$ HOME=myhome ./myscript.py
```

Но лучше всё-таки поддерживать опции, например при помощи [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my util')
parser.add_argument("-m", "--home", dest="home", help="Set home")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.home)
```

Comment: "Например, ..." указывает на то, что есть и другие если предложенное не подходит :)

Comment: Логически это, конечно же, корректно, но все же как пример имеет смысл показывать более-менее актуальные модули)

Comment: Тоже верно, поправил :)